# посылка ajax запроса с использованием angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Доброго

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    //жмякнем по div
    $(".mydiv1").click(function(){

        //возьмем какие ни будь данные
        var param2 = $(".mydiv2").val();
        var param3 = $(".mydiv3").val();

        //пошлем ajax запрос
        $.ajax({

            url:"page.php",
            type:"POST",
            cache:true,
            data: {
                param2: param2,
                param3: param3
            },
            success: function(html){
                $(".mydiv4").html(html);
            }

        })

    });
});
</script>
```

Собственно есть такая штука, angularjs. Все круто, но не пойму как сделать на нем ajax запрос аналогичный, тому, что написал выше?

P.s. с тем что написал проблем нет

Comment: `$http.post(...).then(function(html){...})`

Comment: мм.. можно развернутый пример? просто после чтения справки по ангулару мой вопрос и возник

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
      param2: param2,
      param3: param3
  },
  url: '/page.php'
}).then(function successCallback(html) {
    $(".mydiv4").html(html);
}, function errorCallback(response) {

});
```

Comment: Вот полная документация https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Как вариант.
`$http.post('/page.php', {
      param2: param2,
      param3: param3
}).success(function(response){
 $(".mydiv4").html(html);
}).error(function(){

});`

Comment: пример шикарен, за исключением, что в моем указан конкретный клик по диву, т.е. код страницы можно писать отдельно от скриптов, в ангуляре это пока не понимаю как сделать

Comment: Если честно agular вообще не знаю но на крайняк можно на обычном js